# PFLogInViewController no longer recognized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I am building an iPhone app on iOS 8 with the latest version of Parse.

Does anybody know if the PFLogInViewController is still a thing? I'm having an incredibly hard time including it in my project. Everything else with Parse works perfectly fine. The only problem is that PFLogInViewController and PFSignUpViewController (and their delegates) are not recognized whatsoever

I have a theory that Parse might have discontinued their functionality in their latest versions. Can anybody offer any insight ? Thanks in advance

Comment: They're still recognized in iOS 8. There must be something else wrong with your code.

Comment: it's still a thing, probably, always will be a thing, have you deleted your frameworks or import tags perhaps?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I included all of the libraries that were included in the Parse package.

Comment: I said there must be something else wrong with your *code* so I'm assuming you meant that response to be for @soulshined... but I think soulshined might be right about that fact that you're forgetting your import tags.

Comment: Yes. Parse separated their libraries a while back. Now they have an exclusive library for UI elements. So import ParseUI to the project if your upgrading from a SDK that didn't support ParseUI

Comment: Here's what your looking for [ParseUI Reference](http://blog.parse.com/2014/11/06/introducing-the-new-parseui-for-ios/) thanks @LyndseyScott let us know if this doesn't work.

Comment: @soulshined this looks pretty good, thanks so much!

Comment: @soulshined Yeah, I think that's a great answer and addresses an important change in Parse... Maybe you should post it as a proper answer so future answer-seekers can find it a bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Parse SDK version 1.5.0, [see changelog [HERE](https://parse.com/docs/downloads)] Parse has segregated their UI elements from functional code. If you have upgraded your frameworks to the latest version from a previous version of parse that did not support ParseUI you must include the new import tags for your projects to recognize UI components.

Simply call this in your view controllers that relate to your PFLoginViewController:

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```