# PFLogInViewController not found with ParseUI.framework already imported?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, parse-platform

In the ios sdk, `PFLogInViewController.h` and `PFSignUpViewController.h` are not in the `headers` folder in `Parse.framework`, I found them in `ParseUI.framework`. When I try to add them to my `UIViewController`, they are not recognized by Xcode.

I dragged the Parse UI framework to the window in xcode > copy items if needed, and it appears well in Build Phases > link binary.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
#import "PFLogInViewController.h" //PFLogInViewController.h is not found

@interface LoginConfigVC : UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>
```

Would you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul you don't have to #import the header files they are included in the ParseUI import (as part of their new move over to UI dedicated elements see [here](http://blog.parse.com/2014/11/06/introducing-the-new-parseui-for-ios/) or see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27896088/2353523))

All you have to do is call the `PFLogInViewController` in whatever View Controllers `viewDidAppear` method so delete your `#import "PFLogInViewController.h"` line and here is a brief example of calling the interfaces:

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

     if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
         // Create the log in view controller
         LoginViewController *logInViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
        [logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton];

        // Create the sign up view controller
        SignupViewController *signUpViewController = [[SignupViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

       // Assign our sign up controller to be displayed from the login controller
       [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];
       // Present the log in view controller
       [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
     } 
}
```

For a more thorough walkthrough see their [guide](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views)

Comment: I edited my post, could you have a look at it? Thanks

Comment: @Paul are you using storyboards or xibs?

Comment: thanks I will start a new thread about the error handling, it is maybe better. I created a new project, and I would like to change the alert message, I added a alertController in didFail...SignUp, the log appears well, but the alert message is still the old one.